# Protected member is unknown for derived class

Tags: c++

I found an open source class library for Graphs. When I included it in my project it has many errors and I tried to fix them. But there is a compile error that I can not solve it.

Base class:

```
template <typename K, typename W, typename T>
class _base_graph
{
//... 

protected:
    std::map<K, T> nod;
    std::list<edge> edg;
};
```

Derived class:

```
template <typename K, typename T = void*>
        class graph : public _base_graph<K, void*, T>
{
//...
public:
    void add_edge(const K& k1, const K& k2);
};
```

Method body:

```
template <typename K, typename T>
void graph<K, T>::add_edge(const K& k1, const K& k2)
{
    if (nod.find(k1) == nod.end() || nod.find(k2) == nod.end()) // <-- error!!
        throw std::string("add_edge: Node does not exist");

    // ...
}
```

But my gcc compiler show me an error:

> error: ‘nod’ was not declared in this scope

**You can find and test mycode in [this](http://ideone.com/F5u7xI) online compiler.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need

```
this->nod.find(k2);
```

or

```
_base_graph<K, void*, T>::nod.find ....;
```

The base and the derived classes are templates, and in your code `nod` is a non-dependent name, and so is looked up at the point of `graph`'s declaration. This is the first phase of the *two-phase lookup*. At this stage, it is impossible for the compiler (provided it follows the name lookup rules of the standard) to know what `nod` means, *because it does not consider the base class until the second phase*. So it is necessary to tell the compiler that `nod` should be looked up in the second phase. To do this, we explicitly tell it that `nod` is in a base class by using one of the forms above.

The reason for this behaviour is that at the point of the derived class' *definition*, it should not possible to know what `_base_graph<K, void*, T>::` contains, to allow for specializations of the template that add and even hide names. So the trick above makes sure that the names are looked up at the point of the derived class' instantiation, when all the information is available.

In summary, there are two issues in play here:

1. `nod` is not a dependent name, so it would be looked up in the first phase.
2. The base class template, which declared `nod`, is not available until the second phase, so the name cannot be resolved.

By using `this->nod` or `_base_graph<K, void*, T>::nod`, we are explicitly dealing with a dependent name, forcing the lookup to take place in the second phase.

See points 7 to 10 [here](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#two-phase).

Thanks to @DavidRodriguez-dribeas for clarifying some of the finer points of the two phase look-up.

Comment: Thanks, but why there is not same issue for method and they do not need `this->` ?

Comment: @MasoudM.  You would have the same problem with a method, at least with a standards compliant compiler.

Comment: The description is good, but it would be better if you used proper terms, in particular *dependent*/*non-dependent* name; and explained how the extra qualification transform a name from the second set to the first.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that was my intention before the edit, but I have found `base<T>::name` described as both dependent and non-dependent, so I will have to wait until I can have a look at the standard later. This stuff still confuses me sometimes.

Comment: @juanchopanza: `base<T>::name` is clearly dependent on `T`, how could it not depend on `T`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas that is my thinking. I am just not sure why, if the name is dependent, the lookup is attempted at the point of declaration if the name is dependent, i.e. why do we have to give a hint to the compiler. I am starting to think that my understanding of this process is wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I understand that by 'hint' you mean the potential use of `typename` or `template`, that is required because without actually resolving the lookup or that hint the compiler cannot know what the name represents, and without that knowledge it would be impossible to complete the rest of the first phase lookup: `base<T>::x * y` --> is that a multiplication of a member of the base `x` times a `y` that needs to be looked up, or else is that the declaration of a local variable `y` of type pointer to a nested type `x`? What is the meaning of `y` in the rest of the function?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I meant the use of `this->x` or `Base<T>::x` in the derived type. So you are saying `x` is dependent, but the compiler still needs to find the name in the first phase. Is my understanding correct? I thought all lookup of dependent names would happen the 2nd phase.

Comment: `x` without qualification is non-dependent, both `this->x` and `base<T>::x` are dependent. For dependent names the compiler does not lookup in the first phase, but it needs to know the *kind* (is it a member, a member type, a member template?) to understand the rest of the code and complete the first phase lookup of the rest of the function. `base<T>::x*y` can be either a declaration of a pointer or a multiplication, `base<T>::x<U> y` can be either the declaration of a variable or the expression `(base<T>::x  < U) > y` requiring lookup of `y` and `U`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19485/discussion-between-david-rodriguez-dribeas-and-juanchopanza)

Answer (score 3):

`nod` is a member of a dependent base (one that depends on template parameters). You either need to qualify the call with the name of the base, e.g. `_base_graph<K, void*, T>::nod` or with `this->nod`.

Alternatively you can also bring in names with `using _base_graph<K, void*, T>::nod` in <s>either function or</s> class scope.