# Why `expected primary-expression` when it seems ok

Tags: c++

Following my previous question
[Protected member is unknown for derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359679/protected-member-is-unknown-for-derived-class)

I cannot understand which part of that line is wrong, Any idea?

There is a compile error here:

```
template <typename K, typename T>
bool graph<K, T>::is_edge(const K& k1, const K& k2)
{
  if (this->nod.find(k1) == this->nod.end() || this->nod.find(k2) == this->nod.end())
    throw std::string("is_edge: Node does not exist");

  if (k1 < k2) // Below line makes error: expected primary-expression!!!!
    return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), edge(k1, k2)) != this->edg.end();
  return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), edge(k2, k1)) != this->edg.end();
}
```

Or, what's wrong with this statement:

```
std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), edge(k1, k2)) != this->edg.end();
```

The complete code is [here](http://ideone.com/erbzWA), where you can test and compile it.

Comment: Can you please **simplify** this code and get rid of *everything* that is irrelevant to the problem?

Comment: What is this `edge(k1, k2)`?

Comment: @Nim: I linked it to an online code compiler. Putting whole code here is not useful so the link is better.

Comment: Heh. I've seen the code. I concur with Masoud. The code compiled find except for this problem, and considering the amount of it, thats pretty nice to see for a change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve through the derived class to the base class like so (at least LLVM can =):

```
template <typename K, typename T>
bool graph<K, T>::is_edge(const K& k1, const K& k2)
{
    typedef typename graph::edge edge;

    if (this->nod.find(k1) == this->nod.end() || this->nod.find(k2) == this->nod.end())
        throw std::string("is_edge: Node does not exist");

    if (k1 < k2)
        return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), edge(k1, k2)) != this->edg.end();
    return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), edge(k2, k1)) != this->edg.end();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the complete code, I see `edge` is also defined in the base class. You must also tell the compiler it's a dependent name, like this:

```
if (k1 < k2) // Below line makes error: expected primary-expression!!!!
  return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), typename _base_graph<K, void*, T>::edge(k1, k2)) != this->edg.end();
return std::find(this->edg.begin(), this->edg.end(), typename _base_graph<K, void*, T>::edge(k2, k1)) != this->edg.end();
```

Comment: You can just say `typename graph::edge` rather than giving the base-class name; that's enough to indicate that it's a nested type name.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. And, is there any wise way to reduce this long `typename _base_graph<K, void*, T>`?

Comment: @MasoudM. See Mike's comment.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, that's it